# Remembering user login on parse.com android?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Hi I am specifically trying to use the parse api for login but I am having trouble getting the code to check if the user has logged in before. I posted the question on the parse website but no answers. 
I found this code in a tutorial but am unsure where to place it in my launcher activity.

```
Intent intent;

if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null){
  intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
}else{
  intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
}

startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

Launcher Activity Code

```
/**
 * Activity which displays a login screen to the user, offering registration as
 * well. Based loosley on the default Login template. 
 * 
 * @author Trey Robinson
 */
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_view, LoginFragment.newInstance());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_forgot_password:
                forgotPassword();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the forgotPassword dialog 
     */
    private void forgotPassword(){
         FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
         ForgotPasswordDialogFragment forgotPasswordDialog = new ForgotPasswordDialogFragment();
         forgotPasswordDialog.show(fm, null);
    }


    @Subscribe
    public void onSignInStart(AuthenticateUserStartEvent event){
        showProgress(true, getString(R.string.login_progress_signing_in));
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onSignInSuccess(AuthenticateUserSuccessEvent event){
        showProgress(false, getString(R.string.login_progress_signing_in));
        Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginSuccess);
        finish();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onSignInError(AuthenticateUserErrorEvent event){
        showProgress(false, getString(R.string.login_progress_signing_in));
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onForgotPasswordStart(UserForgotPasswordStartEvent event){
        showProgress(true, getString(R.string.login_progress_signing_in));
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onForgotPasswordSuccess(UserForgotPasswordSuccessEvent event){
        showProgress(false,getString(R.string.login_progress_signing_in));
        Toast toast =Toast.makeText(this, "A password reset email has been sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onForgotPasswordError(UserForgotPasswordErrorEvent event){
        showProgress(false, getString(R.string.login_progress_signing_in));
        Toast toast =Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occured. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to just try it somewhere?  This site works best when you show your actual code and describe the current results (and what's wrong with them).  (My uneducated first guess would be to try it in `onSignInStart`)

Comment: I tried putting it in a lot of places within the on create method with no luck . The onSignInStart only runs once a person submits a login but I want it to check if the person has logged in before on the start of the application.

Comment: You mean once an user logged in your app,then second time onwards dont ask  login ..just bypass that login and show profile page..is that you want?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution

Add in Login Fragment this code:

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(mUserNameEditText.getText() + "",
            mPasswordEditText.getText() + "", new LogInCallback() {
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (user != null && e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            getString(R.string.login_success),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SplashScreen.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); 


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            getString(R.string.login_failed),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });
```