# Add an additional button to login screen of a Parse project

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm developing an android using parse. I need to add an additional button to the login screen of the project to skip the login. I am a beginner for parse development. Somebody please help.

Comment: I think adding an button in the screen, doesn't have any connection with using parse.

Comment: But the xml file is in the parse UI library. Therefore I cannot make changes there.

Comment: Thanks @DroidWormNarendra I found the solution. I have to create the xml file in my layout folder.

Comment: @Choxmi [Possible duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24067620/2183890)